# How Can I display specific formats from ansible_facts using ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am new to Ansible, I got the task to display below format from host machine using ansible playbook.
output - RHEL 7.7 (x86_64)

I have written using shell script -
os_version=$(cat $RHAT_RELEASE 2>/dev/null | awk '{printf("%s ", $0)};END{printf("\n")}' | sed 's/Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release/RHEL/g' | cut -f1 -d'(' | sed 's/ +$//g')

```
     RHEL_VERSION=$(echo $os_version | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d'.')

     RHEL_MINOR=$(echo $os_version | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f2 -d'.')

     RHEL_ARCH=$(uname -i)
```

But as per requirement, I should format the output using ansible_distribution or ansible_facts

Please help in writing ansible playbook

Comment: Need a output - RHEL 7.7 (x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine some of the `ansible_facts` variables, e.g.

```yaml
---
- name: Print Distribution Info
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_version }} ({{ ansible_architecture }})"
```